# How to prevent text from "moving" when an image is overlayed? (so image is overlayed on text)

Tags: css

The "hand drawn" read arrow on the right forces the text "Free...Course" to move to the right. I do not want that text to move. I want the arrow to just be overlayed on top.
I've tried making the text "style=dislay:block  and float:none" but that didn't work.

Any other ideas?
[image]

```
  Want free treatment materials&nbsp; 
      <img  alt="" height="197" src="../images/arrow-sketched-down.png"  width="154" style="float:right; position:absolute; "><strong><br>work on your goals?</strong></div> 
 <div class="text-center mt-1 mb-1" style="display:block;float:none">
      <h2>Free Speech-Language Treatment Course</h2>
      <p class="auto-style1">Every day is an opportunity for recovery.&nbsp; 
      Don't&nbsp;miss&nbsp;a&nbsp;single&nbsp;day. I'll&nbsp;provide&nbsp;you&nbsp;the&nbsp;tools&nbsp;&amp;&nbsp;knowledge&nbsp;for&nbsp;faster&nbsp;speech&nbsp;&amp;&nbsp;language&nbsp;recovery</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the position to `absolute` for the red arrow?

Comment: Can you give us a code snippet for that

Comment: @CarlEdwards Yep, I'd just figured that out.
If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @ClayNichols Gotcha covered.

Answer (score 1):

Take the red arrow out of your current document flow by setting its' `position` to `absolute`. Also make sure to set its' parent's `position` to `relative` so that any vertical/horizontal adjustments made to the arrow are in fact *relative* to its' bounding container.

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
}
```